# Express 2014 with Advanced Services, can't create Full Text Index

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014-express

I can't confirm that Full-text service is running or installed. There is no sql server full text search [instance] running as a service on the machine. I thought this would be installed with advanced services? But it's not there.
When I run

```
select fulltextserviceproperty('isfulltextinstalled')
```

I get a '0' which according to other posts means that it is not installed. I installed Sql Server Advanced Services 2014 with all tools checked. And in Sql Server Configuration Manager I see the service 'Sql Full Text Filter Daemon Launcher' and it is running. Is there another service that I don't have running that needs to be there? How do I install full text search for Sql Server Express 2014 With Advanced Services or install the service so that I can run full text search? Please help !

When running this command

```
 CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG GftExGiftFTCat;
```

I get the message:

```
Cannot use full-text search in user instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out that I was using localDb and full text search does not work on LocalDb. So I switched over to Sql Express. 
Question - I'm developing a MVC 5 application with code first. Because I'm not using localdb anymore will I run into any development issues or any roadblocks?